# RSS usage tracking

Tags: rss

Is there a way to track if anyone is using your RSS feeds?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to define "using," such as: pulling the feed or reading what they pulled?

Answer (score 0):

Feedburner ([feedburner.google.com](http://feedburner.google.com/)) can give you all sorts of stats. I know there are others providing similar services, but that's the one I've used in the past.

Comment: Yes, instead of having people subscribe to the feed URL on your site you have them subscribe to a feedburner URL and usage on that is tracked

Answer (score 0):

Feedburner does exactly that: http://feedburner.google.com

Comment: Strangely enough, while Feedburner shows no subscribers for my feeds, today I saw a referrer coming from Google Reader and when I followed the link I got to a page with my feed results. Now, I don't use Google reader and have never seen this page before... Puzzled a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a small single-pixel invisible image in the HTML inside the description tags. This image can be loaded dynamically from a server-side script. When the script executes, you will know some user is reading your RSS feed content and the image has loaded because of that. This way you get to monitor the stats rather than rely one some other service.